# OpenLayers2 to OpenLayers3 WMS

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, wms

I have a working OpenLayers 2 (OL2) application currently. To create the WMS layer in OL2, I use:

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('WMS', '../../WMS/floorplan?', { layers: '@Model.LayerName', version: '1.3.0', format: "image/png", shapefile: '@Model.ShapeFile'  }, { isBaseLayer: true, singleTile: false, yx: [] });
```

My equivalent on OpenLayers 3 (OL3) is:

```
var layers = [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: '../../WMS/floorplan?',
              params: {
                  'LAYERS': '@Model.LayerName',
                  'SHAPEFILE': '@Model.ShapeFile'
              }
          })
      })
    ];

var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: layers,
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            extent: ext,
            projection: parameters.projection,
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 0.5
        })
    });
```

However, the OL3 one only gets a single tile from the WMS call while the OL2 one gets all the tiles and renders it correctly. What could the issue be?